# How can I create an algorithm for display all possible character combinations as a list in python?

Tags: python

The inputs for the function are

1. a list of characters, eg: `['a','1']`
2. length of combinations

The function should output a list of all possible character combinations as a list.

For example, for input `['a','1']` and length of 2, the function should output:

```
[['a','a'],
['a','1'],
['1','a'],
['1','1']]
```

and if the length is 3, the output should be:

```
[['a','a','a'],
['a','a','1'],
['a','1','a'],
['a','1','1'],
['1','a','a'],
['1','a','1'],
['1','1','a'],
['1','1','1']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` with the `repeat` parameter:

```py
from itertools import product

data = ['a', '1']
n = 3

print(list(list(p) for p in product(data, repeat=n)))
```

This gives an output of:

```py
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', '1'], ['a', '1', 'a'], ['a', '1', '1'], 
['1', 'a', 'a'], ['1', 'a', '1'], ['1', '1', 'a'], ['1', '1', '1']]
```